# Rails Triple Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models `Report`, `Server`, and `Platform`. I need to execute a query that involves triple joining all 3 models and making the query based on that. But I get the following error whenever I try to triple join

ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'platform' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Here are my models

**Report**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :server

 delegate :company_id, :to => :server

    class << self

        def method(url, base_url)
            Report.joins(:server).joins(:platform).where(:platforms => {:company_id => 5}).all
        end
    end

end
```

**Server**

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :reports
 belongs_to :platform

end
```

**Platform**

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :company_id

 has_many :servers

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: (note the `s` in `platform` it is needed because the table names are plural):

```
Report.joins(:server => :platform).where(:platforms => {:company_id => 5}).all
```

Comment: Sorry I had some typos. You answer however is correct. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how you specify inequalities in the where clause for the joined field?